# CPU spikes to 100%

Tags: sitecore-commerce, xconnect, commerce-engine

Often getting the below error from my log files. Every time this error occurs the CPU spikes from 93% to 100%. Searched for the fixes and workaround but couldn't find any solution.

After recycling the AppPool the CPU usage gets back to normal. Issue occurring in `Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 with Sitecore Commerce`.

```
35552 04:08:02 ERROR PostSessionEndPipeline failed.
Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
Message: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.CustomModels.PageEvents.Converters.ConvertPageEventDataToVisitedProductDetailsPageEvent.TranslateEvent(PageEventData pageEventData, VisitedProductDetailsPageEvent pageEvent)
   at Sitecore.Commerce.CustomModels.PageEvents.Converters.ConvertPageEventDataToVisitedProductDetailsPageEvent.CreateEvent(PageEventData pageEventData)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertPageEventDataToEventBase.ConvertToEvent(PageEventData pageEventData)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectEventPipeline.ConvertToXConnectEventProcessorBase`1.Process(ConvertToXConnectEventPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.PipelineBasedModelConverter.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ConvertToXConnectEvent>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XdbModelExtensions.<ToEvents>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XdbModelExtensions.ToInteraction(VisitData visitData, IEntityReference`1 contact, ModelConverterBase converter)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.ConvertToXConnectInteractionPipeline.ConvertToXConnectInteractionProcessor.Process(ConvertToXConnectInteractionPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.PipelineBasedModelConverter.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ConvertToXConnectInteraction>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<SaveVisit>b__1(IXdbContext xdbContext)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<ExecuteWithExceptionHandling>b__0(IXdbContext c)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Monitor>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SubmitSessionContextPipeline.Run(SubmitSessionContextArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.HttpSessionContextManager.Submit(Session session)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.SubmitSession.Process(CommitSessionPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.CommitSessionPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Run>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Monitor>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.PostSessionEnd.CommitSession.Process(PostSessionEndArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.EndSession.PostSessionEndPipeline.Run(PostSessionEndArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Web.Application.RaiseSessionEndEvent(HttpApplication context)
```

Comment: do you have any data in the submit queue folder?

Comment: No. I had earlier but I cleared those and still I’m getting this error.